# Apache Drill query column names from csv data

Tags: csv, apache-drill

I have a csv file in local file system which i can query like

```
SELECT * FROM  dfs.`/Users/HOF/Downloads/cars.csv`;
```

Note: I have

```
  "skipFirstLine": true,
  "extractHeader": true,
```

in the storage plugin for csv

Data in the csv file looks like

```
Name,Mileage,Cylinders,Displacement,Horsepower,Origin
ford torino,17,8,302,140,USA
ford galaxie 500,15,8,429,198,USA
...
```

**Now i want the field information to be returned by a query**
like

```
| COLUMN_NAME | DATATYPE |
|-------------|----------|
| Name        | *        |
| Mileage     | *        |
| Cylinders   | *        |
...
```

I tried with

```
DESCRIBE dfs.`/Users/HOF/Downloads/cars.csv`;
```

but getting an empty list of column

```
|-------------|-----------|-------------|
| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE |
|-------------|-----------|-------------|
|-------------|-----------|-------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently DESCRIBE does not support tables created in a file system [1]. It works with views though, so if you'll create view over your data, you might get desired result. See more in describe section.

[1] https://drill.apache.org/docs/describe/